# Memory Card Game "if else" statement not working (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, springboard

I can't seem to find what is wrong with my code. Here is what the project requires:

For this assignment, you’ll be building a memory game in the browser using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Your goal is to build a card-based memory game.
Players will be shown a collection of cards, face down, and can click on a card to reveal what’s underneath.
After clicking on two cards, the game should check to see whether they match. If they do, they will remain facing up.
If not, the cards should remain displayed to the player for one second, and then flip back down.*
The goal of the game is to match up all the pairs.*

When playing the game with my current code, the cards don't back over when they aren't matched with each other. I think the last "if else" statement in my code is the reason to this. I also think it could just be corrected by creating another if statement

[ if (flipCount === 2 & firstCard.style.classList !== secondCard.style.classList) ]

But wouldn't the current else statement suffice?

```js
const gameContainer = document.getElementById("game");
let hasFlippedCard = false;
let firstCard, secondCard;
let noClicking = false;

const COLORS = [
  "red",
  "blue",
  "green",
  "orange",
  "purple",
  "red",
  "blue",
  "green",
  "orange",
  "purple"
];

// here is a helper function to shuffle an array
// it returns the same array with values shuffled
// it is based on an algorithm called Fisher Yates if you want ot research more
function shuffle(array) {
  let counter = array.length;

  // While there are elements in the array
  while (counter > 0) {
    // Pick a random index
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);

    // Decrease counter by 1
    counter--;

    // And swap the last element with it
    let temp = array[counter];
    array[counter] = array[index];
    array[index] = temp;
  }

  return array;
}

let shuffledColors = shuffle(COLORS);

// this function loops over the array of colors
// it creates a new div and gives it a class with the value of the color
// it also adds an event listener for a click for each card
function createDivsForColors(colorArray) {
  for (let color of colorArray) {
    // create a new div
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");

    // give it a class attribute for the value we are looping over
    newDiv.classList.add(color);

    // call a function handleCardClick when a div is clicked on
    newDiv.addEventListener("click", handleCardClick);

    // append the div to the element with an id of game
    gameContainer.append(newDiv);
  }
}

// TODO: Implement this function!
function handleCardClick(event) {
  // console.log(event.target);
  if (noClicking) return;
  // if the card has been flipped, nothing will happen
  if (event.target.classList.contains("flip")) return;
   //change background color of card to class name
   let selectedColor = event.target.className;
   event.target.style.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
   // add class name of flip to 1st and 2nd clicked card's class
   event.target.classList.add('flip');
   //create variable holding the total number of cards flipped (with class name flip)
   let flipCount = document.querySelectorAll('div .flip').length;
   //define first card and second card variables
  if (!hasFlippedCard) {
    hasFlippedCard = true;
    firstCard = this;
  } else {
    hasFlippedCard = false;
    secondCard = this;
  }
  //  console.log("eventtarget is"); console.dir(event.target);
  //  console.log("firstcard classname is", firstCard.className);
  //  console.log("secondcard classname is", secondCard.className)
  //  console.log("Card is flipped?", hasFlippedCard);
  //  console.log("First card is", firstCard);
  //  console.log("Second card is", secondCard);
  //  console.log("number of flips", flipCount);
  //  if two cards have flipped and the classes do not match. 
  //  Make no change to new background color
   if (flipCount <2) return;
   if (flipCount === 2 & firstCard.classList === secondCard.classList) {
     function matchedCards(){
       firstCard.classList.remove('flip');
       secondCard.classList.remove('flip');
      }
      matchedCards();
    }
    else {
      noClicking = true;
     function resetCards(){
       firstCard.classList.remove('flip');
       secondCard.classList.remove('flip');
       firstCard.style.backgroundColor = "";
       secondCard.style.backgroundColor = "";
       noClicking = false;
     }
     setTimeout(resetCards, 1000)}
     
    // run resetFlips function after one second
  
  //  console.dir(event.target);
  }

 // when the DOM loads
createDivsForColors(shuffledColors);
```

```css
#game div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 15%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #c9e0e8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Memory Game!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Memory Game!</h1>
    <div id="game">
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The javascript AND operator is && not & (which is the bitwise comperator).

Comment: Thanks! I changed the code, but the cards are still not flipping over when not matched.

Comment: Next thing then. It can't be a good idea to compare classLists straight off. Though it may or may not work in this instance, you must guarantee the order of classes and (I assume) trimming spaces. I think the places where you use `.contains` is much more sensible. (This as well might not be the source of your problem however)

Comment: I think comparing classList === classList  might compare if two objects are the *same* objects. You could try the `==` operator instead for a quick test. I'd try to stick to the `===` operator if possible though...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! That method makes a lot more sense to use than comparing classes. Also, I found my mistake that I left the .style in the last if statement when I was initially comparing cards color backgrounds instead of the cards classes. Took it out, but cards still not flipping over.

Comment: change to `if (flipCount == 2 && firstCard.className == secondCard.className) {`

Comment: Thank you ariel!!! The cards are now flipping over!

Comment: If you use this code to answer my question, I'll accept the answer! Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property of an element returns a live [DOMTokenList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) which in JavaScript is an object with methods to add, remove or check if a class exists in the list.

Now separate objects in JavaScript never compare as equal, even if they have the same properties. (Noting the value `null` is *not* an object).

So the conparison expression

```
 firstCard.classList === secondCard.classList
```

is always `false` - the token lists are not the same.

You could compare the `className` properties directly to see if the cards have the same class names *in the same order* but adding and removing classes risks changing the order of class names in the space separated `className` string, so it may not work in this case.

You can store string values reliably on an element using their `dataset` object property, or you could give each card an `id` value to lookup a JavaScript object recording card details using card ids as property names. Amongst other possibilities you might like to devise to access card properties.

Good luck with the assignment.